# Does groovy have an easy way to get a filename without the extension?

Tags: java, file-io, groovy, file-extension

Say I have something like this:

```
new File("test").eachFile() { file->  
println file.getName()  
}
```

This prints the full filename of every file in the `test` directory.  Is there a Groovy way to get the filename without any extension?  (Or am I back in regex land?)

Comment: Sometimes files don't have an extension but do have a `.` in them.

Answer (score 56):

I believe the grooviest way would be:

```
file.name.lastIndexOf('.').with {it != -1 ? file.name[0..<it] : file.name}
```

or with a simple regexp:

```
file.name.replaceFirst(~/\.[^\.]+$/, '')
```

also there's an apache commons-io java lib for that kinda purposes, which you could easily depend on if you use maven:

```
org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils.getBaseName(file.name)
```

Answer (score 39):

The cleanest way.

`String fileWithoutExt = file.name.take(file.name.lastIndexOf('.'))`

Comment: it produces not intuitively expected results in the following cases:

`assert ['.foobar', 'foobar'].collect { it.take(it.lastIndexOf('.')) } == ['', '']`

Answer (score 16):

Simplest way is:

```
'file.name.with.dots.tgz' - ~/\.\w+$/​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Result is:

```
file.name.with.dots
```

Comment: This is elegant! It removes everything after the last dot in the file name (and the last dot)

Answer (score 9):

```
new File("test").eachFile() { file->  
    println file.getName().split("\\.")[0]
}
```

This works well for file names like:
    foo, foo.bar

But if you have a file foo.bar.jar, then the above code prints out: foo
If you want it to print out foo.bar instead, then the following code achieves that.

```
new File("test").eachFile() { file->  
    def names = (file.name.split("\\.")
    def name = names.size() > 1 ? (names - names[-1]).join('.') : names[0]
    println name
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The FilenameUtils class, which is part of the apache commons io package, has a robust solution.  Example usage:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils

String filename = '/tmp/hello-world.txt'
def fileWithoutExt = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(filename)
```

This isn't the groovy way, but might be helpful if you need to support lots of edge cases.

Comment: apache commons every time!  "compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'" at time of writing...

Answer (score 5):

Maybe not as easy as you expected but working:

```
new File("test").eachFile { 
  println it.name.lastIndexOf('.') >= 0 ? 
     it.name[0 .. it.name.lastIndexOf('.')-1] : 
     it.name 
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, where a filename ends & an extension begins depends on the situation.  In *my* situation, I needed to get the basename (file without path, *and* without extension) of the following types of files: { `foo.zip`, `bar/foo.tgz`, `foo.tar.gz` } => all need to produce "`foo`" as the filename sans extension.  (Most solutions, given `foo.tar.gz` would produce `foo.tar`.)

Here's one (obvious) solution that will give you everything up to the first "."; optionally, you can get the entire extension either in pieces or (in this case) as a single remainder (splitting the filename into `2` parts). (Note: although unrelated to the task at hand, I'm also removing the path as well, by calling `file.name`.)

```
file=new File("temp/foo.tar.gz")
file.name.split("\\.", 2)[0]    // => return "foo" at [0], and "tar.gz" at [1]
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't see mauro's answer until after posting this. This should have been a comment, since it's almost identical, but just without the forEach/closure. I'll leave this for now, since it is simpler to read if unfamiliar with the `{ file -> yada yada }` syntax (which was of course in the original question, but otherwise irrelevant to the problem).

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions better.
A function like the following would do the trick:

```
def getExtensionFromFilename(filename) {
  def returned_value = ""
  m = (filename =~ /(\.[^\.]*)$/)
  if (m.size()>0) returned_value = ((m[0][0].size()>0) ? m[0][0].substring(1).trim().toLowerCase() : "");
  return returned_value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note**

```
import java.io.File;

def fileNames    = [ "/a/b.c/first.txt", 
                     "/b/c/second",
                     "c:\\a\\b.c\\third...",
                     "c:\\a\b\\c\\.text"
                   ]

def fileSeparator = "";

fileNames.each { 
    // You can keep the below code outside of this loop. Since my example
    // contains both windows and unix file structure, I am doing this inside the loop.
    fileSeparator= "\\" + File.separator;
    if (!it.contains(File.separator)) {
        fileSeparator    =  "\\/"
    }

    println "File extension is : ${it.find(/((?<=\.)[^\.${fileSeparator}]+)$/)}"
    it    =  it.replaceAll(/(\.([^\.${fileSeparator}]+)?)$/,"")

    println "Filename is ${it}" 
}
```

Some of the below solutions (except the one using apache library) doesn't work for this example - c:/test.me/firstfile

If I try to find an extension for above entry, I will get ".me/firstfile" - :(

Better approach will be to find the last occurrence of File.separator if present and then look for filename or extension.

**Note:**
(There is a little trick happens below. For Windows, the file separator is \. But this is a special character in regular expression and so when we use a variable containing the File.separator in the regular expression, I have to escape it. That is why I do this:

```
def fileSeparator= "\\" + File.separator;
```

Hope it makes sense :)

Try this out:

```
import java.io.File;

String strFilename     =  "C:\\first.1\\second.txt";
// Few other flavors 
// strFilename = "/dd/dddd/2.dd/dio/dkljlds.dd"

def fileSeparator= "\\" + File.separator;
if (!strFilename.contains(File.separator)) {
    fileSeparator    =  "\\/"
}

def fileExtension = "";
(strFilename    =~ /((?<=\.)[^\.${fileSeparator}]+)$/).each { match,  extension -> fileExtension = extension }
println "Extension is:$fileExtension"
```

Answer (score -3):

```
// Create an instance of a file (note the path is several levels deep)
File file = new File('/tmp/whatever/certificate.crt')

// To get the single fileName without the path (but with EXTENSION! so not answering the question of the author. Sorry for that...)
String fileName = file.parentFile.toURI().relativize(file.toURI()).getPath()
```

Comment: Neither do I :) I apparently provided an example on how to get the file name without the path, but WITH extension. So I did not answer the question of the author.