# append timestamp to a filename in groovy

Tags: groovy, timestamp

I'm creating an excel report of all test case results using groovy. Since the files are getting over ridden after each execution I want my filename to appended with current timestamp so that they wont get overridden.

Below is the code which I have tried:

```java
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import jxl.*
import jxl.write.*
def count=0,i=1,j=1
def inputFileName,outputFileName
today = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSS Z")
def outputFile = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("outputFileName")
outputFile.renameTo(new File(outputFile+"_"+today))
log.info outputFile
```

I'm getting below error:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.renameTo() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.File) values: [C:\TestData\output.xls_2020-01-09 16:13:02.00805 +0530] error at line: 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code so that you don't have any illegal characters like `:` in filename.

**Update:**
`renameTo` is a function in `File` type and you were tryng to call it with `string` type. Hence, you were getting the error.

```java
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import jxl.*
import jxl.write.*
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils

def count=0, i=1, j=1
def inputFileName, outputFileName

def outputFile = new File(testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("outputFileName"))

// Perform other operations on the file.
//
// End

today = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss.SSSSS Z")
def fileWithoutExt = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("outputFileName"))
outputFile.renameTo(new File(fileWithoutExt + "_" + today + ".xls"))
log.info outputFile
```

Comment: It is giving the output file name as: "C:\TestData\output.xls_2020-01-09 17.43.01.00790 +0530"

Comment: Yeah but I want to append it before the extension

Comment: Take a look at [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569547/does-groovy-have-an-easy-way-to-get-a-filename-without-the-extension/34472525#34472525) and also I have updated the answer.

Comment: It is not renaming in local. If I print the file name its showing as "\TestData\output_2020-01-09 18.12.10.00397 +0530.xls" but in local its output.xls only